# Python and tkinter: NameError: name 'askyesno' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkmessagebox

I get this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__ return self.func(*args)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Base\utility.py", line 68, in clear
askyesno('Clear', 'Press YES or NO')
NameError: name 'askyesno' is not defined
```

When I try to run this:

```
if askyesno('Clear', 'Press YES or NO'):
 do some code
```

I have tried `tkMessageBox.askyesno` but still getting the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `from tkinter import messagebox` to import `messagebox` and then:

```
 if messagebox.askyesno('Clear', 'Press YES or NO'):
```